# What is wrong with this code?even i tried retaining CF objects, it crashes in lion

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-foundation

```
CGContextRef ctx = CGContextRetain([[NSGraphicsContext currentContext] graphicsPort]);
CGColorRef color = CGColorRetain([NSColor colorWithCalibratedRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0.5f].CGColor);

CGContextSaveGState(ctx);
{
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(ctx, color);
    CGContextFillRect(ctx, dirtyRect);
}
CGContextRestoreGState(ctx);

CGColorRelease(color);
CGContextRelease(ctx);
```

Comment: Where is it crashing? What's the error message?

Comment: [NSCalibratedRGBColor CGColor] Unrecognised selector sent... looks like an ARC early release error. but i have retained CF objects.

Comment: That's nothing to do with retaining; The "Unrecognized selector" error provides much business on Objective-C StackOverflow questions.  It's one of our favourites and where you should start looking for your answer.

Comment: Thank you very much i will look into it. Also going through NSColor class reference again made me realise that CGColor API is available on 10.8 and above. that might be the case here

Comment: @trojanfoe: To be fair, most of those questions *are* over-release questions.

Comment: @PeterHosey Is it?  I had the feeling they were mostly because the coder simply didn't know the class of object they were dealing with; and was especially true of JSON-parsing code.

Comment: @trojanfoe: Maybe it's shifted since ARC. It used to be that 9 out of 10 “does not respond to selector” classes were “it died and something else took its place”.

Comment: @PeterHosey Ah OK - yeah I think it has changed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like the error message says, NSColor objects don't respond to `CGColor` messages in Lion—that method was added in 10.8. On 10.7, you will have to convert the NSColor to a CGColor yourself.

Here's a function that does the conversion. On 10.8, it just returns the NSColor's `CGColor`. If that isn't available, it does the conversion itself.

```
CGColorRef PRHCreateCGColorWithNSColor(NSColor *color) {
    if ([color respondsToSelector:@selector(CGColor)]) {
        CGColorRef cgColor = [color CGColor];
        return cgColor != NULL ? (CGColorRef)CFRetain(cgColor) : NULL;
    }

    NSString *colorSpaceName = [color colorSpaceName];
    NSColorSpace *colorSpaceNS;
    if ([colorSpaceName isEqualToString:NSNamedColorSpace] || [colorSpaceName isEqualToString:NSPatternColorSpace]) {
        colorSpaceNS = [NSColorSpace genericRGBColorSpace];
        color = [color colorUsingColorSpace:colorSpaceNS];
    } else {
        colorSpaceNS = [color colorSpace];
    }
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = [colorSpaceNS CGColorSpace];

    size_t numberOfComponents = CGColorSpaceGetNumberOfComponents(colorSpace);
    CGFloat components[numberOfComponents];
    [color getComponents:components];

    return CGColorCreate(colorSpace, components);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for being patient and understanding the exact problem and replying with the good code which helped a lot..cheers. have a nice day:)

Comment: Even though it works the colour i get in lion is darker than colour i get in Mountain lion. e.g. selectedMenuItemColor gives Dark blue and Blue respectively. any thoughts on this?

Comment: @SuhasAithal: They might've changed it between OS versions. Try logging the contents of the `components` array.

Comment: Only Blue is 1, red and green are 0.

Comment: @SuhasAithal: That's pure blue. Are you sure you're using the right format specifiers—floating-point instead of integer?

Comment: @SuhasAithal: Never mind—I just tried it (just got home). On Lion, it is indeed pure blue (when converted from the named color space to the generic RGB color space). On Mountain Lion (10.8.4)… it crashes, trying to send a `model` message to the color space. I haven't tried on 10.8.5.

Comment: Exactly the same for me :).. i need to get same colour though, no luck till now.

Comment: @SuhasAithal: The problem with that is that the “color” may not be a single color. This is very common among named colors such as `selectedMenuItemColor` and `windowBackgroundColor`: the “color” is actually a pattern or gradient. Reducing this to one color in any color space is a lossy act—the “color” was never a single RGB color to begin with, so you're throwing away everything else. Whatever single color you reduce it to *will* look different from the original “color”. If you want fidelity, you can't do it that way. If you're saving and restoring the color, consider using NSKeyedArchiver.

Comment: But i wonder how apple seems to get exact blue colour while converting using [NSColor selectedMenuItemColor] CGColor] in MLION?

Comment: @SuhasAithal: They're not. The presence of a decimal fraction doesn't mean the value is any more “exact”. The selected menu item color is not a single color on Mountain Lion, either; *any* single color you get back from a conversion is (at best) an approximation, such as an average.

Comment: @Mazyod: What do you mean “leaks”? It's a function, not a method, and [its name contains the word “Create”, signaling that it returns an ownership reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/Concepts/Ownership.html), which means you need to release it. That's true no matter what OS version you're on, and the function's 10.8 code path retains the CGColor to achieve this consistency.

Comment: @PeterHosey My bad, for some reason I didn't realize you retain the 10.8 implementation.